# VBA changing font size of one character in specific string (MSWORD MACRO)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying replace the font size of one character in specific string.

[image]

This one creates the word I want but I cannot get it incorporated with a replace function.

```
Sub logo()
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
With Selection.Range
 .Font.Reset
 .Text = "EXAMPLE"
 .Characters(2).Font.Size = 8
End With
End Sub
```

This one replaces the whole word. I cannot get it incorporated with a character function.

```
Sub RedoFonts()
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Text = "EXAMPLE"
        .Replacement.Text = "EXAMPLE"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Replacement.Font.Size = 9
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Replacement.Font.Name = "Times New Roman"
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

Any way to merge these two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code searches the Active Document for the string "this" and changes the "h" in it to a font size of 20.

```
Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="this", Forward:=True
If myRange.Find.Found = True Then
    myRange.Find.Execute FindText:="h", Forward:=True
    If myRange.Find.Found = True Then myRange.Font.Size = 20
End If
```

Comment: Is there a way to implement this with a ms word macro?

Comment: oops totally missed that you wanted ms word macro, ill edit answer accordingly

Comment: What about that letter but only in a specific word? So not all H's

Comment: figured it out. added .characters after myrange.     If myRange.Find.Found = True Then myRange.Characters(2).Font.Size = 8

Comment: its working great. Is there a way to loop through the doc?